# R: possible bug in `factor`?

Tags: r, date, r-factor

Is this a possible bug in `factor` or am I missing something here?

```
xx <- seq.Date(Sys.Date(), length.out=5, by="1 day")

factor(xx) # Works fine!
[1] 2013-07-12 2013-07-13 2013-07-14 2013-07-15 2013-07-16
Levels: 2013-07-12 2013-07-13 2013-07-14 2013-07-15 2013-07-16

factor(xx, levels=unique(xx)) # Generates NAs.
[1] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
Levels: 2013-07-12 2013-07-13 2013-07-14 2013-07-15 2013-07-16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because factor levels are `character`s, while `xx` is `Date`. Passing a `character` vector to the levels argument works as expected:

```
factor(xx, levels=as.character(unique(xx)))
[1] 2013-07-12 2013-07-13 2013-07-14 2013-07-15 2013-07-16
Levels: 2013-07-12 2013-07-13 2013-07-14 2013-07-15 2013-07-16
```

Comment: I did find that. But the help `?factor` says this: The default is the unique set of values taken by `‘as.character(x)’` in which case I will expect the original to work as well. Is it a bug inasmuch as it is different from the documented behavior?

Comment: No, you overwrite the default if you pass something to `levels`.